# Execute a ruby script in scala or convert logic in scala

Tags: ruby, scala, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very small ruby script that I need to run in scala either by straightway running the sript which according to resources online is possible through `org.jruby` but the dependency doesn't work for me in `build.sbt` or by writing the same logic in scala but I am not able to get the logic correct for Ruby's `ActiveSupport encryptor`.
The intention is to create a scala web api which folks can utilize to retrive the passwords based on inputs. Thanks in advance.
Following is the script that I need to run:

```
# Usage: ./gen_password.rb SECRET ID URL
# Example: ./gen_password.rb 73191239133f 1234567 myshop.com
# Note: 73191239133f is a fake secret. It will not work.


require "active_support/all"


SECRET = ARGV[0]
ID = ARGV[1]
URL = ARGV[2]


encryptor = ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor.new(SECRET)

puts("#{ID}+#{URL}+#{Time.now.utc.to_i}")
puts encryptor.encrypt_and_sign("#{ID}+#{URL}+#{Time.now.utc.to_i}")
```

Comment: I would just google the **Java** encryption packages, you don't have anything too complex there.

Comment: If you could share your attempt at re-implementing this in Scala and what error it causes, it would be easier for the community to help you fix whatever is preventing you from getting the logic right.

Comment: Sure let me share the scala implementation

Comment: Rails 4 for real or is that a mistag?